# Eliminate specific value from Jmx exporter through config Yaml

Tags: java, yaml, prometheus, jmx, sre

Here is the current **Jmx exporter** pattern:

```
pattern: 'metrics<name=resilience4jCircuitbreakerState.name.(.*).state.(.*), type=gauges><>Value'
name: 'x.y.z.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.state'
labels: {name: "$1", kind: "$2" }
type: GAUGE
```

Current Output:

```
x_y_z_resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="open",name="a",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="closed",name="b",} 1.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="half_open",name="c",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="half_open",name="d",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="forced_open",name="e",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="disabled",name="f",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="disabled",name="g",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="forced_open",name="h",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="closed",name="i",} 1.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="closed",name="j",} 1.0
```

Which actually works fine. But to improve cardinality we decided not to expose 0.0 values modifying the Yml (if there is anyway).

The expected output for the above pieces of sample is,

```
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="closed",name="b",} 1.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="closed",name="i",} 1.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="closed",name="j",} 1.0
```

Please feel free to comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally below regex works for me,

```
^(?!0(\.0)?$)
```

Here is the verification of my result,

[Click here to verify the result](https://regex101.com/r/c5uPXR/1)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a 5 `x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state` metrics for every `name`, each with a different `kind` label, one with a value of `1.0` and the others with a value of `0.0`.

In this case if you do not expose `0.0` and a circuitbreaker changes through all states all metrics will report `1.0`.

To reduce cardinality, you should remove the `kind` label and set the value to a state.

Instead of this:

```
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="disabled",name="a",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="closed",name="a",} 1.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="open",name="a",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="half_open",name="a",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="forced_open",name="a",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="disabled",name="b",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="closed",name="b",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="open",name="b",} 1.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="half_open",name="b",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="forced_open",name="b",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="disabled",name="c",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="closed",name="c",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="open",name="c",} 0.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="half_open",name="c",} 1.0
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{kind="forced_open",name="c",} 0.0
```

You should report something like this:

```
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{name="a"} 1.0 # 1 represents "closed"
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{name="b"} 2.0 # 2 represents "open"
x_y_z__resilience4j_circuitbreaker_state{name="c"} 3.0 # 3 represents "half_open"
```

Comment: The idea will work, but the cost is to redesign all of our dashboards. Actually, I was wondering why regular publishing doesn't work for me `.*1.*`. When I am using this expression it gets filtered all the zero values but duplicates the row which creates another problem. Actually, I wanted to use `.*[^0.]+` which I was expecting to be fit but it's also doesn't help.